# Why is image not being displayed after picking from gallery in release build of flutter app?

Tags: flutter

I am using image_picker and image_cropper plugins,
It all works fine in debug build, but not in release builds

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] (and earn a badge while you are at it) / Also read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

For starters, please include a [mcve] to your question. Otherwise, it might take a lot more time and a heap of guessing to figure *exactly* where the issue lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going back to some stable build, you have errors due to AndroidX incompatibilities for sure